# converting simple method as class method and accessing instance variables

Tags: python-2.7

I have a below instance information which I have no access about instantiation

```
a.name = "Head"
a.id = "xxx"
a.no = "noinfo"
a.clear = True
a.use = "About"
```

and a different method

```
def download(app):
    myapp = MyAPP()
    myapp.execute(app.name,app.id,app.clear)
```

how do i associate my function `download(app)` with the same instance by invoking `a.download()` as the meaning of the function would be more appropriate only if I associate with it

Please see me as novice in python. any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: why do you need to invoke it as a method? just invoke it as a function

Comment: @hop In my code I feel it is appropriate to call as  `a.download()` rather than `someclass.download(a)`

Comment: why is it even a method? show code. there is nothing here to answer, otherwise